# Open port to remote access PostgresSQL on Ubuntu

Tags: postgresql, ubuntu

I opened a PostgreSQL port by adding a line in `/etc/postgresql/10/main/pg_hba.conf`

```
host    mydatabase             myuser             my_ip_adress/32            md5
```

and then opening the port like this:

```sh
sudo ufw allow 5432/tcp
```

Is this secure enough? Our should I also limit the IP adresses for port 5432 in ufw / iptables?

Answer (score 1):

"Secure enough" depends a lot on your requirements.

I would say that that is good enough for normal purposes.  An easy improvement would be to use `scram-sha-256` instead of `md5` (don't forget to change the `password_encryption` parameter and set a new password).

If your database contains the secret algorithm that the NSA uses to break TLS encryption, you might want to use a different authentication method like Kerberos that uses central identity management rather than database passwords.